# What would be a good way of determining number of decimal places from a format string?

Tags: .net, formatting, numbers, double, decimal

I'd like a function that looks like this:

```
int GetDecimalPlaces(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null);
```

The inputs would be exactly the same as those which can be legally passed to methods responsible for formatting numbers, e.g., `double.ToString`, `decimal.ToString`.

The output would be an `int` indicating the lowest number of decimal places required by the format string.

So here are a couple of example inputs/outputs I would expect (let's just say leaving `formatProvider` as `null` results in the current culture being used):

```
Input | Output
------|-------
N2    | 2
0     | 0
0.000 | 3
g     | 0
0.0## | 1
```

If possible, I'd like to do this the "right" way; i.e., without hacks. But if hack I must, I would also appreciate *good* hacking suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to take a whole number, like 1, and format it, then parse the string to count the number of decimal places.  I guess this qualifies as a hack, but it should work pretty reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert to a string, then search for the separator character location. subtract this value from the length of the string.
Again possible a hack but???