# RegEx: fetch number of decimal places from DisplayFormat string

Tags: .net, regex

Can anybody help to create a regex to handle this sutuation.
There is a display format string for numerics values, which can be in following format
positive_value_format;negative_value_format.
Positive and negative formats can be for example '#,##0.00;(#,##0.0000)' or '#,##0;(#,##0.0)' or '#,##0' - it means that one positive value should be shown with 2 digits after the dot, another - with no digits.

so I need to create regex to handle this 3 cases, what is the number of decimal places for positive and\or negative values.

'#,##0.00;(#,##0.0000)' -> 2, 4
'#,##0;(#,##0.0)' -> 0, 1
'#,##0' -> 0

I've found following questions, but they are not answered or use parsing strings instead of RegExp - [What would be a good way of determining number of decimal places from a format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089661/what-would-be-a-good-way-of-determining-number-of-decimal-places-from-a-format-s), [identify the number of decimal places based on the format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127444/identify-the-number-of-decimal-places-based-on-the-format-string)

Comment: What do you mean with "handle"? Extract numbers?

Comment: I need to know _count_ of decimal places for both positive and negative values: '#,##0.00;(#,##0.0000)' -  #,##0.00 is the part of DisplayFormat for positive values, I should get 2 as output for group Positive; then is the separator between poz i negative parts ';' and then goes (or not goes) negative, with brackets - (#,##0.0000), so the output (count of decimal places) is four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with all 3 provided strings

```
        string pat = "#,##([0-9]([0-9.]*?|$))($|;[(]#,##[0-9]([0-9.]*?)[)])";
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pat);

        int lengthA = m.Result("$2").Replace(".", "").Length;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Result("$4")))
        {
            int lengthB = m.Result("$4").Replace(".", "").Length;
        }
```